# 'Enough that' usage

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the below two dialogues, are the usages of "enough that" appropriate?

> A: what are you doing? I think you must be working hard!
>
> B: Yes, I'm working hard enough that I can finish what you've asked me to do by 12. So don't worry about it.
>
> A:  Are you cheating on me? Seeing that you try to avoid talking about her, it seems to me as if you were hiding something.
>
> B:  No. I'm not cheating on you. I love you enough that I can tell you everything. The truth is that she is just a friend.
>
> A. How much money do you have? It's too expensive for you to buy it.
>
> B. I have enough money that I can buy it right now.

Comment: Your a) samples have numerous syntax errors. May I correct them?

Comment: "until 12" in the first example should be "*by* 12".  Finish {something} by {some time}.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Yes, of course!! I would appreciate it.

Comment: Done. Hope it's OK.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your b) versions are all appropriate uses of "enough that".